# "Bike Factory" or "Bikes Factory" title is more usual?

Tags: titles, verb-agreement

In Lithuanian language we usually say in plural "Bikes Factory".

But I have checked by Google results count that there it is more usual in English to use the title "Bike Factory" instead of plural "Bikes Factory". Am I right? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is more usual in English to use the title "Bike Factory" instead of plural "Bikes Factory". Am I right?

It is not only more usual, "Bikes Factory" is incorrect. This explained as the first noun is acting as an adjective and thus it does not accept inflections (it is, practically, an uncountable noun). If we take the example of a 'real' adjective: "A **red** door" -> "**Red** door**s**" are correct BUT **Reds** door**s** is wrong

Answer (score 0):

It is not just more usual to use "Bike factory", it is the only choice according to this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=15&smoothing=3&content=bike+factory%2Cbikes+factory&year_end=2008&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbike%20factory%3B%2Cc0) ([ref.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bike%20factory%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)); therefore, you should use that form.

Comment: thanks for very uself tools!

Comment: Yes, this is general. Even shoes (which are sold in pairs) are made in _shoe_ factories. According to Ngram there was a brief period when [clothes factory](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&smoothing=3&content=Clothes+factory&year_end=1960&year_start=1920&direct_url=t1%3B%2CClothes%20factory%3B%2Cc0) was used but even then [garment factory and clothing factory] dominated it completely. Not only that but 'clothes' is unusual because it doesn't have a singular form. No one says "I've just bought a new clothe" and "a new cloth" is just a piece of fabric, not a garment.